# how char is changed to int while doing calculations in c?

Tags: c, binary, char, int

In the below program the output is "Not same" although a and b have the same value? I googled it and found that the value of the a and b is converted to int.And new value of a is -5 and that of b is 251.I am not getting how they are becoming so different after typecasting?
a in binary is 11111011 and b is 11111011 so when they are typecasted into int
a should become -53, how it is -5 .Please explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char a = 0xfb;
unsigned char b = 0xfb;

printf("a = %c", a);
printf("\nb = %c", b);

if (a == b)
  printf("\nSame");
 else
 printf("\nNot Same");   
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get 11111011 = 117?  It is 128+64+32+16+8+2+1 = 251.

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `\n` at the end of line: `printf("...\n", ...)`. Your way looks strange (maybe even wrong?) `printf("\n...", ...)` ... The final output of the program above **is not** terminated by a newline (I'd say it is not a *line*)

Answer (score 2):

No, the problem is not that they are converted to `int` the problem is most probably your line

```
char a = 0xfb;
```

On your system `char` is probably a `signed` data type, but `0xfb` is an unsigned value that doesn't fit into the range of the target type. So it is converted in an implementation defined manner, usually to a negative number. And so `a` and `b` definitively don't have the same value.

Comment: For gcc the default for char is signed.  (Prob. so EOFs can be grabbed...)

Comment: Same for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Jim How does a `signed char` enable that "EOFs can be grabbed"?

Comment: If (for example) you have a getc returning to an unsigned char (instead of a char) then an EOF (-1) is converted to a positive number and may then not be detected.

Comment: @Jim `getc()` _always_, per the C spec., returns an `int` in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF` without any regard to `char` being signed or unsigned.  Assigning the result of `getc()` directly to a `char` (signed or unsigned) does lose the ability to differentiate between `EOF` and some `char`.  Robust code assigns the results of `getc()` to an `int` exactly for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not saying the having getc() assign to a char is a good idea.  I'm saying it happens.

Answer (score 0):

The char a has a value range of -128 to +127.  The unsigned char b has a range from 0 to 255.  The same bit values  (11111011) mean different things because one is signed and the other is unsigned.

Comment: Note: a `char` could have a range that is the same as `unsigned char`.  Best to think of `char` of having the the same range as either `unsigned char` or `signed char`, and not -128 to 127.

Comment: Most all chars (gcc and Visual Studio) default to signed.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` have same binary representation as `char`. But when comparison operation is performed on `a` and `b`, they are first converted to int. `a` is a signed `char`, when it is converted to an `int`, its value becomes -5 (signed value of `0xfb`). `b` is unsigned char, when it is converted to an `int`, its value becomes 251. The values -5 and 251 have different representations as `int`, so we get the output as “Not Same”.

Answer (score 0):

`0x` means the number is in hexadecimal form.

`fb` in hexadecimal is `11111011`.
for signed number, it is `-5`
and for unsigned, it is `251`.
Signed numbers are represented in 2's complement form.
so if a number is in 2's complement form, then it converted in decimal as below:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
-(2)^7 2^6 ------------------------------------------------ 2^0
-127+64+32+16+8+0+4+1
=-5
```

for unsigned numbers just find the decimal equivalent of `11111011` = `251`